# What are the different Ruby debugging plugins for VIM?

Tags: ruby, debugging, vim, vim-plugin

I've tried a few Vim debugging tools for Ruby, but they are littered  with bugs (as far as i can tell). Anyone know of a really stable debugger for Ruby & Vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try [vim-ruby-debugger](http://github.com/astashov/vim-ruby-debugger)? It should work fine on Linux/Mac OS X. I'm a developer of that debugger, so if you have any problems with it - feel free to ask me. :)

Comment: Awesome :-) I vill certainly let you know if I find anything buggy.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it's supposed to work on non-Rails Ruby scripts? I ran `:Rdebugger %` and nothing happened. I then tried `$ rdebug --client` but it said `Errno::ECONNREFUSED`.

Comment: Same question about using it with non-Rails Ruby scripts. An edit to the answer would be great.

Comment: @ssedano Yes, it's [not working](https://github.com/astashov/vim-ruby-debugger/issues/94), and no commits in the last four years. :(

Comment: @Sparhawk just noticed - you've answered 02.02 02:02:20 :)

Comment: FYI for anyone still coming across this: I couldn't find any debugger that still worked with Ruby >=2.0, so wrote a little tool to set/remove Byebug breakpoints: https://github.com/kmewhort/vim-byebug-breakpoints.